# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list' con algoritmo de valor mínimo de cambio de monedas

Tags: python

Basándome en el algoritmo en [este video de hacker rank](https://youtu.be/sn0DWI-JdNA), he intentado crear mi propio algoritmo que devuelva el valor que estoy buscando.

Básicamente, para ahorrarte 10 minutos, el algoritmo de ese video es recursivo y almacena la información que devuelve en cada iteración en algún lugar, en el caso del video es un hashmap. Lo capcioso viene porque este algoritmo va ha hacer una accion diferente dependiendo de los valores actuales. De allí viene el nombre de "Memoization".

Ese algoritmo te devuelve varias combinaciones que a mi caso en particular no ayudan, así que intente crear mi propio algoritmo.

Yo necesito encontrar el valor mínimo de cambio dada una denominación de monedas mexicana (1, 2, 5, 10). Así que lo que busco es crear un algoritmo que devuelva la primer combinación que encuentre y encaje.

```
import array

#aqui se crean 4 pilas de 1, 2, 5 y 10 monedas
uno = [1 for i in range(10)]
dos = [2 for i in range(10)]
cinco = [5 for i in range(10)]
diez = [10 for i in range(10)]

monedas = [diez, cinco, dos, uno]
#esta pila almacena las demas pilas de monedas 

cont = len(monedas)-1
#contador para indices de arrays

cont2 = 0
#cuenta las iteraciones que lleva el programa

cant = int(input("dame el cambio a regresar: "))

temp = [cant]
#temporal sera una variable que se ira restando conforme avance el
#metodo en su recursion.

res = ""
# res es el diccionario donde se almacenara
# las combinaciones de monedas resultantes

#el punto de este algoritmo (cambio(etc,...)) es devolver la menor
#combinacion de monedas posibles

# este es un algoritmo que no garantiza el minimo valor logico posible
# de cambio pero intenta maximizar el tiempo

#este algoritmo va devolviendo un valor diferente cada vez que
# se itera, y este valor se va concatenando junto con otros en
# un string, que va a terminar siendo el resultado


def cambio(temp, monedas, cont, res, cont2):

    if (temp >=  monedas[cont]):

    #si la cantidad a dividir en mas monedas es mayor que
    #la moneda seleccionada en la pila de monedas
       temp.insert(cont2+1, temp[cont2] -monedas[cont])
    
       print("$",temp,"- $",monedas[cont])
       print("cambio: ",res)
       res = res + temp + "-"
    
       return cambio(temp, monedas, cont, res, cont2)

    if (temp <= monedas[cont]):
       #si el valor a dividir en monedas es menor
       #al valor de la moneda actualmente seleccionada
       #en la lista
       temp.insert(cont2+1, temp[cont2] - monedas[cont])
        ##cont2 lleva el orden de las monedas de mayor a menor
       print("cambio: ",res)
       res = res + temp + "-" 
       return cambio(temp, monedas, cont-1, res, cont2)

    if (temp == monedas[cont]):
       #si la cantidad a calcular es identica al valor de la moneda
       #que esta seleccionada de la pila
       temp.insert(cont2+1, temp[cont2] - monedas[cont])
    
       print("cambio: ",res)
       res = res + temp + "-" 
       return cambio(temp, monedas, cont-1, res, cont2)

    if (temp == 1):
       ## si el cambio ya alcanzo 1
       temp.insert(cont2+1, temp[cont2] - monedas[cont])
       print("cambio: ",res)
       return 0;

    if (temp == 0):
       ##si el cambio ya alcanzo 0
       print("cambio: ",res)
       return 0
       ## aqui se termina la recursion en el caso de que el valor
       ## restante sea cero



##fin de metodo

cambio(temp, monedas, cont, res, cont2)
```

Al correrlo, da este error:

> dame el cambio a regresar: 8
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\jose miguel\Desktop\python ejercicios\cambio de monedas intento
> 8.py", line 89, in 
> cambio(temp, monedas, cont, res, cont2)
> File "C:\Users\jose miguel\Desktop\python ejercicios\cambio de monedas >intento 8.py", line 44, in cambio
> temp.insert(cont2+1, temp[cont2] -monedas[cont])
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

¿Qué pasa?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `monedas` es una lista de listas mientras `temp` almacena enteros en un principio, lo que causa el error al intentar restar una lista a un entero. Ten cuidado con la comparación `temp >=  monedas[cont]`, eso realiza una comparación entre dos listas: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types. Aclarando lo que quieres; dada una cantidad **finita** de monedas de diferentes valores pretendes obtener una combinación de cambio  de una cantidad dada usando el mínimo número posible de monedas? Lo de finita es importante.

Comment: > _dada una cantidad finita de monedas de diferentes valores pretendes obtener una combinación de cambio de una cantidad dada usando el mínimo número posible de monedas?_ Si. Busco que el algoritmo tope con el mejor resultado mas rapido. Pero eso ya lo resolvi por medio de otro codigo 5 veces mas sencillo. La otra respuesta es muy buena tbh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para resolver este tipo de problemas lo ideal es usar la **PROGRAMACIÓN DINÁMICA** como se indica en el vídeo que publicaste, ahora antes de programar debes implementar una función recursiva que te resuelva este problema, como podría ser?

Primero ahí que fijarse en un aspecto muy importante que es la memorización, es decir, imagina que este problema es como un árbol binario:  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde cada rama es un sub-problema del problema como tal es decir python divide este problema en muchos problemas pequeños fáciles y rápidos de resolver, pero python no es perfecto y en vez de resolver problemas distintos (que serian las ramas del árbol) python repite estos sub-problemas muchas pero muchas veces, hasta el punto en el que este problema para resolverlo se demora muchos minutos o incluso horas, para esto es la memorización, tu guardas esto ya sea en un diccionario o en una matriz para que cuando un problema resuelto no lo repita nunca mas.

Un ejemplo de la cantidad de sub-problemas que python repite es con la ***Sucesión de Fibonnaci***:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te das cuenta hay sub-problemas que el repite muchas veces, imagina con un valor muy grande por ejemplo de 999!

Tu error puede ser debido a una confusión de una comparación lista con entero como decía @FJSevilla, ahora con todos estos aspectos claros el código quedaría algo asi.

```
from sys import stdin

monedas=[1,2,5,10]

def f(i,n):
    global monedas,l
    n=int(n)
    if i>=4 or n<0: return 0
    if l[i][n] != -1: return l[i][n]
    if n ==0: return 1
    else:
        l[i][n]=f(i,n-monedas[i])+f(i+1,n)
        return l[i][n]

def main():
    global l
    l=[]
    for k in range(4):
        l.append([])
        for y in range(30010):
            l[k].append(-1)

    cambio=stdin.readline().strip()
    while cambio:
        n=int(cambio)
        solve=f(0,cambio)
        if solve==1: print("There is only {} way to produce {} cents change.".format(solve,n))
        else: print("There are {} ways to produce {} cents change.".format(solve,n))
        cambio=stdin.readline().strip()
main()
```

Básicamente lo que hace el código es revisar si no lo he visitado, si el indice no esta dentro del rango de la lista, y si el cambio no es de 0 (ya que retorna 1 o 0), si todo lo anterior se cumple procede a comprobar con que casos o monedas puedo hacer el cambio (es decir prueba todos los casos posibles) y ademas lo guarda en la matriz de tamaño **n*m**, donde n es del tamaño de la lista o monedas con las que puedo cambiar y m un tamaño de 30000, le puse este numero grande es porque debe tener espacio suficiente para almacenar hasta 30000 datos (pero se puede cambiar) por lo que en este caso el peor caso es de 30000, pero no puedes poner este valor de primeras ya que para resolver esto necesita el caso de 29999 y este a la vez necesita el de 29998 y así sucesivamente, por lo que debe empezar casos mas pequeños para que los pueda almacenar y así resolver casos muchos mas grandes.

> Este problema lo resolví de la siguiente pagina [Let me count the
>   ways](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=293)

Comment: vaya, muchas muchas gracias por compartir ese codigo. Esta mucho mas limpio y corto que el mio, logra el objetivo original del video de hacker rank. Es un buen ejercicio para poner a pensar tu mente, afortunadamente me pasaron un codigo mucho mas sencillo que logra mi tarea. Lo publique abajo.

Comment: Gracias, el tema de programación dinámica no es nada fácil de dominar  solo haciendo ejercicios una y otra vez, agradezco tu respuesta una vez mas.

Answer (score 2):

El codigo anterior publicado por @david-o es bastante bueno y voy a estudiarlo mas a profundidad. Aun asi, aqui les dejo el codigo que resuelve mi duda original.

```
monedas = [1000,500,200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
N=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad: "))
    for i in monedas:
        if(N/i>=1):
            if(i>=20):
                print("la cantidad de billetes de " +str(i) +" es: "+str(int(N/i)))
            else:
                print("la cantidad de monedas de " +str(i) +" es: " +str(int(N/i)))
        N=N%i
```

Answer (score 1):

Es código en python, es una manera de solucionar el problema del cambio

```
print ("DETERMINAR EL CAMBIO")
#DZUL CANUL JESUS GEOVANY
costo = int(input("Cuanto es lo que costo lo que compro lo que compro\n$PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO\n"))
pago = int(input("Digite la cantidad de dinero con lo que usted pago\n"))
dinero = pago-costo """DETERMINAMOS CUANTO ES EL CAMBIO"""
def cambio(cam):
    if cam == 0: #FUNCIO DE PARADA
    return ""#cambio(cam)
    else:
    if cam >= 200:

print ("Un Billete de 200 mas")
#SI EL CAMBIO ES MAYOR A 200 <br/>PODEMOS DAR UN BILLERETE DE 200 SI NO SALTA A LA SIGUIENTE CANTIDAD
        return cambio(cam-200)#IMPORTANTE PARA QUE LA FUNCIONA RECURSIVA  SE IMPLEMENTE
        """
    IMPORTANTE PARA QUE LA FUINCION RECURSIVA  SE SI PODEMOS DAR UN BILLETE DE 200, TENEMOS QUE RESTARLE Y VOLVER A DETERMINAR 
            SI TODAVIA PODEMOS DAR UNO MAS O NO.
            """
    elif cam >= 100:
    print ("Un Billete de 100 mas")
    return cambio(cam-100)
    elif cam >= 50:
        print("Un Billete de 50 mas")
        return cambio(cam-50)
    elif cam >= 20:
    print ("Un Billete de 20 mas")
    return cambio(cam-20)
    elif cam >= 10:
        print ("Una moneda de 10 mas")
            <br/>return cambio(cam-10)
        elif cam >= 5:
        print("Una moneda de 5 mas")
            return cambio(cam-5)
        elif cam >= 2:
        print("Una moneda de 2 mas")
        return cambio(cam-2)
        elif cam >= 1:
        print("Una moneda de 1 mas")
        return cambio(cam-1)


print(cambio(dinero))
print ("Su cambio es : "+str(dinero))
```